# Why does echo combined with printf displays wrong output?

Tags: php, formatting, printf, echo, string-formatting

Does anyone know why when I execute this :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$eff_theo = array_fill(0, 10, 100);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i)
   echo printf("%5d", $eff_theo[$i]).' ';
echo PHP_EOL;
?>
```

I get this :

```
1005 1005 1005 1005 1005 1005 ...
```

Comment: Don't do `echo printf`, just `printf`.

Comment: What output you're expecting? the echo is just for space I can see. What is 5 in the format specifier for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing `echo` and `printf`.

`printf` returns the length of the formatted string, so your `echo` call is printing out '5'.

Try removing the `echo` and try it again....

Comment: printf returns the length of the formatted string, not the value; it outputs the value

Comment: This is what happens when I try to answer questions when I've not had enough coffee. I'll corrent that - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

printf returns the length of the string you have made, choose either

```
echo sprintf(...)
```

or just

```
printf(...)
```

with no echo

Answer (score 1):

[printf](http://php.net/printf) is a function that outputs your given text to standard output and returns the length of the outputted string.

[echo](http://php.net/echo) is a language construct that is used to output data.  Ultimately you are echoing the return value of the `printf` statement after `printf` outputs its value.

Either use `echo` or `printf`, but not both at the same time.